# How to specify external folder content in the classpath using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am very new to gradle. I am trying to add a folder content (resource folder) in the classpath, but didn't find the right way to do it.

I have a resource folder that is in `C:\tools\resources`, and my project has a total different path (`C:\project\foo`). I want to take into account all files in resources folder: xml, .properties, .configuration, etc...

How can I do so using build.gradle?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why don't you add these files to project?

Comment: Because it's the structure of the software implementation. Why that resource file is out of scope? It's from the r&d team.

Comment: Not sure if gradle can include files external to project.

Comment: When I run the project on eclipse, I can add the folder from Build Path --> add external class, then it's taken into account by grale. But when I run it on IntelliJ, there isn't any feature such as "add to classpath" like the one in Eclipse. But I am pretty sure it's doable in gradle.

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: Forgot to mention it. Yes, it is. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it will be:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets { 
   main { 
      resources { 
         srcDir 'ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_RESOURCE'  
      } 
   }   
}
```

You may also try `new File('ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_RESOURCE').absolutePath` if just passing path won't work.

It's good idea to keep this path under some environment variable to make cooperation easier among different developers/workstations.

Comment: If we include some folder like this inside a Android module how to access the files inside the application context?